# Drawing dashed line in CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, drawing, cashapelayer

I'm drawing a UIBezierPath into a CAShapeLayer, because I want to use strokeStart and strokeEnd to control which sections of the path are drawn. Everything works fine except lineDashPattern is being ignored. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried using `setLineDash` on the UIBezierPath itself. It works if I stroke the path directly into the context (using `[path stroke]`), but doesn't help if I assign the CGPath to the shapeLayer, which is what I need.

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer *)layer;
    UIBezierPath *path = [MyMapPath pathForMap:nil];

    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6.0f;
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = @[@2,@2];
    shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.0f;
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.7f;

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, as I can get it to work for me. But why are you doing this `drawLayer` method at all? This is a very strange and very inefficient way of doing it. Either have a `drawLayer` method that calls `[path stroke]`, or use a `CAShapeLayer` and no `drawLayer` is needed. This code does not belong in a `drawLayer` method.

Comment: After creating the `CAShapeLayer`, you need to add it as a sublayer to some existing on-screen view, using a line of code like `[view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];`. As far as I can tell, the `drawLayer` method that you have there does absolutely nothing, it just creates and then discards a `CAShapeLayer` object.  Whether or not the `pathForMap` method draws anything is unclear.

Comment: @user3386109 I am calling addSublayer in code that is not shown. The above code gets called by the CAShapeLayer in its delegate method.

Comment: @Rob I am new to CoreGraphics so please enlighten. If the layer doesn't draw itself in its delegate method, where should this happen?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're just casting the `layer` arg to a `CAShapeLayer`.  Somehow I misread that as instantiating a new `CAShapeLayer`.  The way the shape layer works is that you instantiate it, sets its path, set some other parameters, add it as a sublayer, and you're done.  No need to set a delegate, no need to draw anything, it draws itself based on the path and parameters that you set.

Comment: @PhilMitchell If you add a `CAShapeLayer` as a layer to a view, you don't have to implement any drawing code yourself. Just add the `CAShapeLayer` and you're done. You can even later change the `path`, for example, and it will automatically redraw it for you. `CAShapeLayer` gets you out of the weeds of writing your own `drawRect` or `drawLayer` routines.

Comment: Okay, that's great to know. I have moved all the code into my view's init method, but still get a solid path. Must be doing something else that's off.

Comment: Yes, it must be something else, as I tested your code above and got a dashed line. The only thing I can imagine is if the path is passing back and forth over itself or if you have another instance of some other `CAShapeLayer` with that path that doesn't specify `lineDashPattern`.

Comment: Okay, solved .. sort of. If I use [@2,@2] for my dash pattern, I get a solid line (on both simulator and device). If I use [@10,@10], I get a nice dashed line! I don't understand that, but I can work with it. Thanks so much for the help -- glad I learned something about CAShapeLayer today!